# Не разворачивается докер на jelastic

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Не разворачивается докер на JELASTIC. Локально все отлично запускается и работает. Тех поддержка предлагает даунгрейд до 14.04. А хотелось бы всё же на 16.04 контейнер собрать.

При разворачивание получаю:

> Can not detect OS version for docker profbis/php-pm-laravel:v1 :
>   ubuntu 16.04

Comment: что именно вы подразумеваете под «разворачиванием»? изложите это прямо в вопросе, пожалуйста. приведите выполняемую команду и полный её вывод.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Не знаю какая команда выполняется. Я просто создаю контейнер в Jelastic а что там у них на серверах происходит не знаю. Поиск по тексту ошибки ничего не дал.

Comment: речь про компанию [jelastic](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelastic)? если да, то обращайтесь в техподдержку **этой компании**. и если они вам ответили, то и придерживайтесь их совета.

Comment: В общем всё проще. В джеластике в ближайшее время не предвидится поддержки 16.04.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Теперь **Jelastic** поддерживает образы основанные на **ubuntu 16.04.**

С уважением, *Jelastic Support Team*

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте,

Нам имезвестно о данной проблеме и она будет исправлена в скором времени.
Пожалуйста, сообщите чем именно обусловлена необходимость использования ubuntu 16.04 и мы постараемся предложить какой-то workaround.

С уважением,
Jelastic Support Team